# JavaScript iPhone detection on iOS 12+ with curve rendering

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone

Recently iOS 12+ has blocked the ability to fingerprint devices using WebGL GPU information, and other methods [outlined here](https://51degrees.com/blog/device-detection-for-apple-iphone-and-ipad). It looks like there is a solution from DeviceAtlas described as follows:

> The new solution involved drawing a complex image on a webpage, hidden
>   to the eye. This drawing is reduced to a short signature that's sent
>   to DeviceAtlas on the server side.
>
> The subtle differences between curve rendering or blurring can point
>   us to a specific GPU, leading to accurate model identification.
>
> The whole process is lightning fast, with almost zero impact on site
>   performance. As Apple sometimes re-use GPUs between models, we
>   cross-reference the drawing signature with certain other identifying
>   properties, eg. screen resolution, pixel ratio etc, to determine model
>   should GPU alone not be enough.

[Full Article](https://deviceatlas.com/blog/ios-122-broke-iphone-detection-fix-now-live)

Looking for any kind of information around a JavaScript method to replicate this type of curve drawing signature generation.